# Unable to communicate websocket when using express server

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I am deploying a HTML file with JS on express nodejs based webserver.
My server is something like:

```
"use strict";
let express = require("express");
let app = express();


app.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log(`${new Date()} - ${req.method} reqest for ${req.url}`);
    next();
});

app.use(express.static("../static"));

app.listen(8090, function(){
    console.log("Serving at 8090")
});
```

I have a html file that i run on this express server. This html file connects to websocket as follows

```
 var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
    url : 'ws://localhost:9090'
  });
```

This code of my program is successful in connecting to webserver. Now when i try to perform some action on this websocket, the connection is automatically disconnected. There is no error and it just disconnects.

If someone can direct on what could be wrong, it will be of great help.

Note: My html file works as expected without disconnecting if i didn't use express.

Comment: So you have a separate WebSocket server running on port 9090? If so, does that log anything at all? How is it implemented?

Comment: @robertklep: It is websocket server based on ROS (robot operating system). It doesn't log anything useful. Also my HTML file works as it should, if i didn't use express or nodejs.